# Entity Framework with npgsql won't accept money datatype

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, npgsql, ef-postgresql

I'm creating a .NET C# app using Entity Framework 5 and PostgreSQL DB. I'm using [npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/) 2.0.12 as Data Provider and Database First approach.

First, I created model files (csdl, ssdl, mdl) and object layer using [edmgen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387165.aspx) with connection string to the postgresql db as parameter.

The edmgen shows a warning when doing it's job:

> warning 6005: The data type 'money' is not supported, the column 'amount' in table 'tablename' was excluded.

Then it all works fine, just that column is not included in the model.
Of course, I'm not happy with that, since I need this column.
I should not modify DB structure.

So, what I did is I modified the model files manually - CSDL, SSDL, MDL respectively:

> ```
> <Property Name="amount" Type="Decimal" Nullable="false" Precision="19" Scale="4" />
> <Property Name="amount" Type="money" Nullable="false" />
> <ScalarProperty Name="amount" ColumnName="amount" />
> ```

I also edited the ObjectLayer by adding this attribute, just like any others in this table.

**Now when I run the app I get:**

> Schema specified is not valid. Errors:  The Type money is not qualified with a namespace or alias. Only primitive types can be used without qualification.

Whose fault is that? EF? npgsql? edmgen?

I found something on [pgfoundry.org/forum](http://pgfoundry.org/forum/forum.php?thread_id=1871&forum_id=519), but changing to numeric doesn't help me.
[User Manual](http://npgsql.projects.pgfoundry.org/docs/manual/UserManual.html) of npgsql indicates that money is a supported type.

**How can I make this thing work with money-typed column?**

Comment: I still don't know where is the fault. I noticed that any custom type isn't supported by edmgen. I still have to figure out if/what needs to be done in Npgsql to give support to it. But the message looks promising as it says that the type should be qualified with a namespace or alias.  So it may be just a matter of configuration.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is to switch to `NUMERIC` as the money type on PostgreSQL has a mind-numbing number of gotchas and is relatively slow.  For example, the currency used is local-dependent, which means that if you change the locale it can suddenly go from 100 meaning $100.00 to 100 Euros, or 100 GBP, 100 Yen, or the like.

I write accounting software, and the money type is so far from being usable for that, I recommend just using NUMERIC.